# Unable to change the location after calling controller function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have read and tried applying all of the approaches I can find on SO but none of them work.

I just basically want to load a different view once the user logs in:

```
myApp.controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$location', function($scope, $rootScope, $location) {

    $scope.Login = function () {
        $location.path('/view1');
        // $scope.$apply(); <- error when trying this
    };

}]);
```

Nothing happens.  If I try $scope.$apply after changing the location then I get the 'action already in progress' error (`http://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope:inprog?p0=$apply`)

I have also tried $location.url, etc.  Can someone please clue me in on what is happening?

Here is my routing config:

```
angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'myApp.filters',
  'myApp.services',
  'myApp.directives',
  'myApp.controllers'
]).
config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/login', {templateUrl: 'views/login.html', controller: 'LoginCtrl' });
  $routeProvider.when('/view1', {templateUrl: 'views/partial1.html', controller: 'MyCtrl1'});
  $routeProvider.when('/view2', {templateUrl: 'views/partial2.html', controller: 'MyCtrl2'});
  $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/login'});
}]);
```

Index File:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title>Foxy Flakes of Steel</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/app.css" />
</head>


<body>


    <div class="container">

        <div class="row" ng-view></div>

    </div>

    <script src="assets/plugins/jquery/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="assets/plugins/angularjs/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/angularjs/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/services.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/filters.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/directives.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is the login.html view:

```
<form class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-3">

    <div class="rounded-gray">

        <div class="row" style="padding: 30px;">
            <div class="input-group" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                <input type="text" placeholder="username" class="form-control" ng-model="username">
            </div>

            <div class="input-group" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                <input type="text" placeholder="password" class="form-control" ng-model="password">
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" style="margin-right: 15px;" ng-click="Login();">Login</a>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: And what is your routing configuration?

Comment: @Andrey - thank you, I have updated my post with the routing info

Comment: and, please, also index.html

Comment: ... index.html content added :-)

Comment: @schomoopy Sorry, could you also show how you bind $socpe.Login to your view? It is in views/login.html, I think.

Answer (score 2):

Two tips that I found;

1. you cannot use $location.path('/view1') during routing is on proress.
2. it's better to check logged in or not at the level of application stage.

   ```
   app.run(['$rootScope', '$location', 'Auth', function ($rootScope, $location, Auth) {
       $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function () {
           if (!Auth.isLoggedIn()) {
               $location.path('/login');
           } else {
               $location.path('/home');
           }
       });
   }]);
   ```

Reference:
 1. [AngularJS and location.path()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18610969/angularjs-and-location-path)
 2. 
[Redirecting to a certain route based on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11541695/angular-js-redirecting-to-a-certain-route-based-on-condition)
 3. [AngularJS- Login and Authentication in each route and controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20969835/angularjs-login-and-authentication-in-each-route-and-controller)

Comment: You are correct on both counts, but this doesn't answer what is happening the Login link is clicked. When your answer and mine are combined a total solution is presented for @schmoopy.

Answer (score 0):

Your Login link should be a button. The href is overriding your ng-click action.

```
<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary pull-right' ng-click='Login()'>
    Login
</button>
```

Also, you don't need the semicolon inside ng-click.

(in-line styles are very bad form, btw)

Answer (score 0):

You may use `ng-href="#/view1"` in your view instead of calling Login method from your controller via ng-click.